Principal Symbol of the Fractional Laplacian on Manifolds
In the euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$, we can define the Fractional Laplacian as
$$(-\Delta)^s f := \int |\xi|^{2s}\hat{f}(\xi)e^{ix\cdot\xi}d\xi.$$
The principal symbol is clearly $p(x,\xi)=|\xi|^{2s}$.
In a compact manifold without boundary $M$, we define the principal symbol of the Laplacian as $p(x,\xi)=\sum_{i,j}^n g^{ij}(x) \xi_i\xi_j$, where we understand that $(x,\xi)\in T^*M$. I am trying to define $\sqrt{-\Delta}$ on $M$. Can I say that $\sqrt{\sum_{i,j}^n g^{ij}(x) \xi_i\xi_j}$ is the principal symbol of $\sqrt{-\Delta}$? Via quantization, does this correspondence hold? Thanks.
